# Approval of an app which is not optimized to iPhone6 series

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store

A app which doesn't have a launch image for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+ is automatically zoomed in to fit to iPhone screens. This kind of app's status bar's size looks bigger than apps which have launch images for iPhone6 and 6+.

Here's a question. If I don't add launch images for iPhone6 and 6+, will it be approved to an app store?

Comment: yep. Approved such apps a week ago.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple's acceptance policy.

Comment: @HoboSapiens Is this kind of question off-topic in SO?

Comment: @trick14 Yes. See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/1864610) on [meta]

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Apple hasn't yet set a restriction on app optimisation for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus. You will have to do it at some point though if you want to continue releasing updates.